# Boot iso in qemu-kvm virt-manager

Tags: kvm, qemu, iso

Can an iso boot in qemu-kvm / virt-manager?  Have bootable usb stick.  The iso will make any usb stick bootable the same way.  Can not boot iso in kvm-qemu / virt-manager.

In virt-manager the iso begins to boot - then KVM hangs at "Booting from Hard Disk..."

From CLI :

```
# qemu-img create -f qcow2 disk_img.qcow 2G
```

> Formatting 'disk_img.qcow', fmt=qcow2 size=2147483648
> cluster_size=65536 lazy_refcounts=off refcount_bits=16

```
# qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2G -hda disk_img.qcow -cdrom Kali64.2019.4-KVM-jun2020.iso -boot d
```

> qemu window appears and hangs at "No bootable device."

Also tried mounting iso with:

```
# kpartx -a -v Kali64.2019.4-KVM-jun2020.iso
```

> add map loop14p1 (254:0): 0 6082560 linear 7:14 2048 add map loop14p2
> (254:1): 0 23945216 linear 7:14 6084608

```
# qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2G -usb -usbdevice disk:/dev/loop14
```

> qemu-system-x86_64: -usbdevice disk:/dev/loop14: could not add USB
> device 'disk:/dev/loop14'

and

```
# qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2G -hda /dev/loop14 -cdrom Kali64.2019.4-KVM-jun2020.iso -boot d
```

> qemu window appears and hangs at "No bootable device."

dd if=iso of=/dev/sdc -> usb boots any machine without error

@ajgringo619 thanks for the hint, but creating in virt-manager vm still boots to "No bootable device..."

Iso should be good - it will boot a computer if burned to usb stick

```
# file Kali64.iso
```

> Kali64.iso: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xb, start-CHS
> (0x0,32,33), end-CHS (0x17a,191,5), startsector 2048, 6082560 sectors;
> partition 2 : ID=0x83, start-CHS (0x17a,191,6), end-CHS
> (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 6084608, 23945216 sectors

```
# fdisk -l Kali64.iso
```

[image: fdisk result]

Comment: Try creating the VM from **virt-manager**, like this: https://www.maketecheasier.com/how-to-use-virtual-machine-manager-linux/. As long as the ISO is good, it should boot just fine.

Comment: yeah idk what the problem is